# Указание интервала

Tags: java

Как можно указать интервал, например, вот такой `(25;100)`, чтоб случайное число из любого отрезка попадало в этот интервал или не попадало? Как производится указание или объявление интервала?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Допустим X - ваше число. Проверка будет выглядеть так:

```
if(x>25 && x<100){
// ваш код;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо теперь понятно! "Sasha121"

Comment: x > 25 && x < 100 = алг. диапазон (25, 100)
    x >= 25 && x < 100 = алг. диапазон [25, 100)
    x >= 25 && x =< 100 = алг. диапазон [25, 100]
    x > 25 && x =< 100 = алг. диапазон (25, 100]

Comment: Огромное спасибо за ответ очень помог! "jrnu"

Answer (score 4):

```
public static int randomNumber(int min, int max) {
    return min + (new Random()).nextInt(max-min);
}
```